# Accidentally deleted folder in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-18.04, data-recovery

One of my client project accidentally deleted and this project was on my aws ec2 instance.I used command "**sudo rm -rf /home/ubuntu/project**" now that folder is removed and i need to recover it asap. I used testdisk and by advanced method it is showing list of deleted folders but the files are not there in that folders and i am getting an error "**No file found, filesystem may be damaged**", i thought i can use fsck command but need to umount disk  /dev/xvda1 but this is the only partition i have in which OS is running , so whenever i use fsck i got error "**disk is mounted and aborting**" then i tried umount but it is giving error of "target is busy". 
i also tried **photorec** may be it recovered the files but it was unsorted and i was not able to identify the deleted files. 
Then I tried **foremost**, it is also giving the same format as photorec.
please help me with this issue.

Comment: Which type of file system have you used for home directories? (ext4/ext3/ext2/…) Use `df -HT` to check it.

Comment: If you use ext file system then check https://askubuntu.com/a/317955/141639

Comment: DONT RUN FSCK or anything on unmounted disk until you have done a bit copy of the disk.

Comment: @AnFi i tried extundelete and it is giving error "Loading filesystem metadata ... 800 groups loaded.
Loading journal descriptors ... Segmentation fault"

Comment: Today, March 31, happens to be the [World Backup Day](https://twitter.com/worldbackupday). It's time to configure automated backups for all your important projects! There should be backups for all scenarios including hardware failures and human errors. Restoring files using any undelete solutions always takes more resources, interrupts the whole server, and possibly leads to only partial recovery. It's no replacement for regular backups.